# I am new and don't understand this syntax error when trying to use the chromedriver with selenium inside spyder

Tags: python, selenium, anaconda

I am trying to just do get all my drivers/packages/etc working so I can create some automated tests for a website. I am new though and I don't understand this syntax error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Users\Username\Documents\pythondrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_id ("fakebox-input").send_keys("Testing")
driver.find_element_by_id ("fakebox-input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "\" is a escape char, below way can work?   I can't use comment function...Have to make an answer..

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Patrick 
Suijk\Documents\pythondrivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.get("http://google.com")
driver.find_element_by_id ("fakebox-input").send_keys("Testing")
driver.find_element_by_id ("fakebox-input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```